# Obtain linenumbers and keep whitespace for XDocument

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-xml

I have an application that uses a textbox to display an XML file.

I use XDocument to keep the line numbers of the nodes

```
_xmlSource = XDocument.Load(path, LoadOptions.SetLineInfo);
```

I also need to keep the whitespace. I'm aware that I can use

```
_xmlSource = XDocument.Load(path, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
```

However, I can't apply both `LoadOptions` to the same `XDocument`.

I need to be able to click on a node from a textbox (custom control) and obtain the xml node based on the line number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
 XDocument.Load(path, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace | LoadOptions.SetLineInfo);
```

to apply both options, because the [`LoadOptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.loadoptions.aspx) enumeration is marked with the [`FlagsAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx).